# How do I get a public IP for my Azure VM?

Tags: powershell, azure, network-programming

I have deployed a VisualStudio web app onto my Azure VM and I need a public IP to the VM so that the public can use my URL to access the web.

The Azure Doc. says:  "Every Virtual Machine is automatically assigned a free public Virtual IP (VIP) address. "
..but I can't find how to get this IP.

I tried "VM > Powershell > ipconfig >  IPv4 Address. . . . . ."
but I cannot ping this IP from the Internet.

Answer (score 3):

"Every Virtual Machine is automatically assigned a free public Virtual IP (VIP) address"

In order to find out the public ip goto-
Azure portal and then your VM dashboard. Here at the right side you see a quick glance tab under which you will be able to see the public IP. Snapshot for your reference-

[image]

Using powershell you can use below command for the same.

```
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName "testservice" -Name "testvm" | select PublicIPAddress
```

**NOTE** - Public IP will be null if instance is in stopped state. To know more on public IP you can read this-

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-instance-level-public-ip/

Answer (score 1):

ICMP (ping) is not permited to bypass Azure gateways, Try check connectivity with other TCP tools (ie. TELNET / SSH / RDP etc ).
To get the IP address of the VM - you can simply go to www.whatismyip.com

Comment: Why should I go to this link for VM's IP. I mean IPConfig command is there. VM dashboard is there. Powershell commands are there. 
Why should someone go to this url ?

Comment: ipconfig shows the configured address on the NIC, while www.whatismyip.com shows 'how the internet see that VM' (which will not be the same if your VM is behind a NAT device (in most cases Azure GW will make NAT for your VM, especially if it has private IP address ie 10.0.0.0/8 or 172.16.0.0/12 or 192.168.0.0/24)